# Creating a dynamic Vue list that can be updated via custom props in HTML

Tags: html, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

New to VueJS. I am trying to build a custom ul component for a webpage that can be populated and updated via custom props (preferably string, but doesn't have to be), specifically in the HTML so that any other dev can simply use/update/add to the custom component with said prop, and it will add a new li through the addition of a second, third, fourth, etc. prop, appending the previous li. I am also struggling to see if more than one input type can be used on a custom prop. For a better explanation heres a coded example of what I currently have and what I would like to do:

```
Vue.component('resources', {
 template: `
      <!-- Resources Component -->
      <div class="resources">
           <div class="heading">
                <p>Resources</p>
           </div>
           <ul class="resource-list">
                <li v-for="item in items">
                     <a :src="item[source]">{{ item.message }}</a>
                </li>
           </ul>
      </div>
 `,
 props: {
      source: {
           type: String,
           default: "."
      },
      message: {
           type: String
      }
 },
 data () {
      return {
           items: [
                { 
                     message: {
                          type: String
                     },
                     source: {
                          type: String,
                          default: "."
                     } 
                }
           ]
      }
   }
 });
```

And in my HTML the component looks like this:

```
<helpful-resources
       message="test"
       source="."
></helpful-resources>
```

This 1000% has a lot of issues, but ideally I would like to have something along the lines of this:

```
<helpful-resources
       item: src="example url 1" message="test message 1"
       item: src="example url 2" message="test message 2"
></helpful-resources>
```

With every addition of a new 'item' appending the previous list item with a new one with the ability to change the src and the message over and over again as needed for however many items are needed in the list.

Any help/clarification would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the parent component:

```
<template>
    <div class="resources">
        <div class="heading">
            <p>Resources</p>
        </div>
        <Helpful-resources :listItems="listItems"></Helpful-resources>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    @import HelpfulResources from '@/path/to/HelpfulResources';

    export default {
        name: 'Resource',
        components: {
            HelpfulResources 
        },
        data() {
            return {
                listItems: [
                  {src: 'link to item', message: 'special message'}, 
                  {src: 'link to item2', message: 'special message2'}, 
                  // More items ...
                ]
            }
        }
    }
</script>

<style lang="scss">
    /* styles */
</style>
```

Your component could be structured like this:
**Helpful-resources.vue**

```
<template>
    <ul class="resource-list">
        <li v-for="(item, index) in listItems" :key="'listItem-'+index">
            <a :href="item.src">{{ item.message }}</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        name: 'helpful-resource',
        props: [ 'listItems'],
        data() {
            return {
                // More data ...
            }
        }
    }
</script>

<style lang="scss">
    /* styles */
</style>
```

**Note** this is styled in the vue-cli fashion, but you can modify it to fit your needs.

**EDIT**

To include it within an html file you would place your Vue components within the body, script tags just below the body tag.

```
<div id="app">
  <resources :source="someData" :message="message" id="r"></resources>
</div>


 <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.10/dist/vue.js"></script>
  <script>

    let resources = Vue.component('resources', {
   template: `<div class="resources">
                            <div class="heading"><p>Resources</p></div>
                <ul class="resource-list">
                    <li v-for="(item, index) in items" :key="index"><a :href="source">{{ item.message }}</a></li>
                </ul>
              </div>`,
   props: {
        number: Number,
        source: {
             type: String,
             default: "."
        },
        message: {
             type: String,
             default: 'No message'
        },
        // Example of multiple data types
        propB: [String, Number] 
   },
   data() {
         return {    
                items: [
                  { 
                       message: this.message,
                       source: this.source
                  }
             ]
         }
     }
   });

    new Vue({
      el: '#app',
      components: {
        resources
      },
      data: {
        someData: 'path/to/source',
        message: 'Special Message'
      },
    });
  </script>
```

Here's a link to the fiddle anyways...[Fiddle](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QRyREv?editors=1000)

As far as updating the list goes, you could use an API call to get data asynchronously or allow users to add info via button or input and use a method. Or if you are talking strictly hardcoding extra values, other developers would add to your file...

Hopefully this helps. If not, please clarify.

Comment: would you then use the component in html as I have used it above? I'm moving toward not using another file as a parent component and building it out all within one

Comment: im essentially asking what this finalized component buildout would look like within an html file when it is being used

Comment: I do not want to have to add new list items through the Vue component, I want the ability to update it strictly in the HTML file in which it lives

Comment: Hi @jazzninja, so the `helpful-resource` component would build out your list dynamically, being what ever size the array `listItems` is. I will write an edit for you if you just want to keep it within a single file.

Comment: worked like a charm. thanks for the explanation and help

Comment: My pleasure! Good luck with your project